How to use filesystem in golang building PWA application, in my example how to create a new file?
I'm trying to build a simple PWA application in golang using go-app package (https://github.com/maxence-charriere/go-app).
I can't understand why the following code doesn't work - no file is created after clicking the button.
After clicking the button I receive the error: "open element1.txt: not implemented on js"
I build the application with two commands: "GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js go build -o web/app.wasm" and "go build" and running with "./app2"
type element struct {
    app.Compo
}

func (e *element) OnClick(ctx app.Context, ev app.Event) {

    //here it doesn't work:
    os.Create(filepath.Join(app.LocalDir("").Static(), "element1.txt"))
}

func (e *element) Render() app.UI {

    //here it works:
    //os.Create(filepath.Join(app.LocalDir("").Static(), "element1.txt"))

    return app.Div().Style("width", "200px").Body(

        app.Button().Styles(map[string]string{
            "width":   "100%",
            "padding": "5%",
            "float":   "left",
        }).OnClick(e.OnClick),
    )
}

func main() {
    app.Route("/element", &element{})
    app.RunWhenOnBrowser()
    http.Handle("/", &app.Handler{})
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}


Well, you never close the file after creating it
I'd update this code to something like this:


func (e *element) OnClick(ctx app.Context, ev app.Event) {

    
    file, err := os.Create(filepath.Join(app.LocalDir("").Static(), "element1.txt"))
    if err != nil {
       fmt.Println(err) // or you can use Printf
       return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    fmt.Println("File created successfully")
}


To be honest, I haven't tested this code, but it should work.

Thank you for improving my code. Still it doesn't work, the result is the same.

What happens if you remove filepath.Join(app.LocalDir("").Static() - in other words if you just create a file in a current path? So file, err := os.Create("element1.txt")

The result is the same.
